# How to handle ResolvableApiException in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to implement a [`CredentialRequest`](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-credentials) inside my composable, but I can't get the `ResolvableApiException` handling to work.

I have created an `ActivityResultLauncher` using `rememberLauncherForActivityResult` and I'm calling it from the `OnCompleteListener` to start the `PendingIntent` as you can see below.

I'd expect this to work, but for some reason I never receive the `ActivityResult`.

```
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
) {
    if (it.resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return@rememberLauncherForActivityResult
    }

    // Handling ActivityResult here
}


val context = LocalContext.current

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    val credentialsRequest = CredentialRequest.Builder()
        .setAccountTypes("https://signin.example.com")
        .build()

    val credentialsClient = Credentials.getClient(context)

    // Read the stored credential if user already signed in before
    credentialsClient.request(credentialsRequest).addOnCompleteListener {
        val result = try {
            it.result?.credential?.id
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            val resolvableException = exception.cause as? ResolvableApiException

            if (resolvableException === null) {
                // Exception not resolvable
                return@addOnCompleteListener
            }

            // User must sign in first
            launcher.launch(
                IntentSenderRequest.Builder(resolvableException.resolution)
                    .build()
            )

            return@addOnCompleteListener
        }

        // Handling result here
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that this might have to do with the `launcher` being outdated because of recomposition, but I'm not sure if that's even possible.

What do I have to do to receive the `ActivityResult`?

Comment: Working on same exact issue now, will dig in and see what I find. Did you ever find a good solution?

Comment: Your setup is actually working fine for me. Only difference I have is that I only trigger the request call when a flag from state is true.